# How to organize this context to collect properly the answers of each participant?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a form for a user register in a conference. But when the user clicks in "Store Registration" it shows an undefined offset error and the issue should be because I'm not organizing correctly this context. The form to register in a conference is different depending on if the "all_participants" column of the conferences table is "1" or "0".

**If all_participants is 1 in the conferences table**

If the conferences table has the column "all_participants" with value "1" that means that is necessary to collect the name and surname of each participant (about each selected registration type). So the form will show form fields to collect the name and surname of each participant. Also if some of the selected registration type(s) have custom questions associated is necessary to collect the answers to that questions for each participant if "all_participants" is 1. In the image above the registration type "General" has a custom question associated "Phone", so its necessary to collect the answers of the two participants there are being registered with the registration type "General".

Image that shows the form of all_participants as "1" in the conferences table

[image]

After the user click in "Store Registration" it should be stored in the tables like below:

[image]

**If all_participants is 0 in the conferences table**

If "all_participants" is "0" the form would have only one field "Phone" because the name and surname are got directly from the authenticated user info. And because "all_participants" is "0" is only necessary also to collect the phone of the user that is doing the registration (the authenticated user), for the other participants is not necessary because "all_participants" is "0". So the form if "all_participants" is "0" would have only one field (Phone) in this case. And the participants table is only necessary to store the name and surname of the user that did the registration, for the other participants can be stored empty "".

Form if all_participants is "0":

[image]

After the user click in "Store Registration" it should be stored in the tables like below:

[image]

HTML of this image context for the case of "all_participants" is 1:

```
<form method="post" id="registration_form" action="http://proj.test/conference/1/conference-title/registration/storeRegistration">

  <h6>Participant - 1 - general</h6>
  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="namegeneral_1">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="namegeneral_1" name="participant_name[]" required="" class="form-control" value="">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="surnamegeneral_1">Surname</label>
    <input type="text" id="surnamegeneral_1" required="" class="form-control" name="participant_surname[]" value="">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="participant_question">Phone?</label>
    <input type="text" name="participant_question[]" class="form-control" required="">
    <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="participant_question_id[]">
  </div>

  <input type="hidden" name="rtypes[]" value="1">

  <h6> Participant - 2 - general</h6>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="namegeneral_2">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="namegeneral_2" name="participant_name[]" required="" class="form-control" value="">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="surnamegeneral_2">Surname</label>
    <input type="text" id="surnamegeneral_2" required="" class="form-control" name="participant_surname[]" value="">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group">
    <label for="participant_question">Phone?</label>
    <input type="text" name="participant_question[]" class="form-control" required="">
    <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="participant_question_id[]">
  </div>

  <input type="hidden" name="rtypes[]" value="1">

  <h6> Participant - 1 - plus</h6>

  <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
    <label for="nameplus_1">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="nameplus_1" name="participant_name[]" required="" class="form-control" value="">
  </div>

  <div class="form-group font-size-sm">
    <label for="surnameplus_1">Surname</label>
    <input type="text" id="surnameplus_1" required="" class="form-control" name="participant_surname[]" value="">
  </div>

  <input type="hidden" name="rtypes[]" value="2">

  <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Store Registration">
</form>
```

When user clicks in "Store Registration" the code goes to the StoreRegistration() to store all the registration info in database:

```
public function storeRegistration(Request $request, $id, $slug = null)
  {
      $allParticipants = Conference::where('id', $id)->first()->all_participants;
      $user = Auth::user();

      $rules = [];
      $messages = [];

      if ($allParticipants == 1) {

          $rules["participant_name.*"] = 'required|max:255|string';
          $rules["participant_surname.*"] = 'required|max:255|string';
      }

      $validator = Validator::make($request->all(), $rules);

      if ($validator->passes()) {

          $total = Session::get('total');

          $registration = Registration::create([
              'conferenec_id' => $id,
              'main_participant_id' => $user->id,
              'status' => ($total > 0) ? 'I' : 'C',
          ]);

          $participants = [];

          for ($i = 0; $i < count($request->participant_name); $i++) {
              $name = ($allParticipants) ? $request->participant_name[$i] : '';
              $surname = ($allParticipants) ? $request->participant_surname[$i] : '';
              $participants[] = Participant::create([
                  'name' => $name,
                  'surname' => $surname,
                  'registration_id' => $registration->id,
                  'registration_type_id' => $request->rtypes[$i]

              ]);
          }

          if (isset($request->participant_question)) {
              foreach( $request->participant_question as $key => $question ) {
                  $answer = Answer::create([
                      'question_id' => $request->participant_question_id[$key],
                      'participant_id' => $participants[$key]->id, // undefined index error is here
                      'answer' => $request->participant_question[$key],
                  ]);
              }
          }
          return redirect(route('user.index', ['user' => Auth::id()]).'#myTickets');
      }
      else{
          dd($validator->errors());
      }
  }
```

I have the Question model that has the getHtmlInput() to generate the HTML for the custom questions and add the required attribute to the field if the "required" column in pivot table "registration_type_questions" is "1":

```
class Question extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'question', 'type', 'conference_id',
    ];
    public static $typeHasOptions = [
        'radio_btn',
        'select_menu',
        'checkbox'
    ];
    public function registration_type()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany('App\RegistrationType', 'registration_type_questions')
            ->withPivot('required');
    }
    public function options()
    {
        return $this->hasMany('App\QuestionOption');
    }
    public function hasOptions()
    {
        return in_array($this->type, self::$typeHasOptions);
    }
    public function getHtmlInput($name = "", $options = "", $required = false, $customtype = false)
    {
        $html = '';
        $html .= $customtype == 'checkbox' ? "<div class='checkbox-group ".($required ? " required" : "")."'>" : '';
        $html .= $customtype == 'select_menu' ? "<select name='participant_question[]' class='form-control' " . ($required ? " required" : "")
            . ">" : '';

        if (empty($options)) {
            switch ($customtype) {
                case "text":

                    $html .= " 
                <input type='text' name='participant_question[]' class='form-control'" . ($required ? " required" : "")
                        . ">";
                    break;

                case "file":
                    $html .= " 
                <input type='file' name='participant_question[]' class='form-control'" . ($required ? " required" : "") . ">";
                    break;

                case "long_text":
                    $html .= "
            <textarea name='participant_question' class='form-control' rows='3'" . ($required ? " required" : "") . ">"
                        . $name .
                        "</textarea>";
                    break;
            }
        } else {
            foreach ($options as $option) {
                switch ($customtype) {
                    case "checkbox":
                        $html .= " 
        <div class='form-check'>
            <input type='checkbox' name='participant_question[]' value='" . $option->value . "' class='form-check-input' >
                <label class='form-check-label' for='exampleCheck1'>" . $option->value . "</label>
        </div>";
                        break;
                    case "radio_btn":
                        $html .= " 
            <div class='form-check'>
                <input type='radio' name='participant_question[]' value='" . $option->value . "' class='form-check-input'" . ($required ? " required" : "") . ">" .
                            '    <label class="form-check-label" for="exampleCheck1">' . $option->value . '</label>' .
                            "</div>";
                        break;
                    case "select_menu":
                        $html .= "<option value='" . $option->value . "'>" . $option->value . "</option>";
                        break;
                }
            }
        }
        $html .= $customtype == 'select_menu' ? "</select>" : '';
        $html .= $customtype == 'checkbox' ? "</div>" : '';

        return $html;
    }
}
```

Then in the view the getHtmlInput() is used like:

```
@foreach($selectedRtype['questions'] as $customQuestion)
  <div class="form-group">
      <label for="participant_question">{{$customQuestion->question}}</label>
      @if($customQuestion->hasOptions() && in_array($customQuestion->type, ['checkbox', 'radio_btn', 'select_menu']))
          {!! $customQuestion->getHtmlInput(
              $customQuestion->name,
              $customQuestion->options,
              ($customQuestion->pivot->required == '1'),
              $customQuestion->type)
          !!}

      @else
          {!! $customQuestion->getHtmlInput(
              $customQuestion->name,
              [],
              ($customQuestion->pivot->required == '1'),
              $customQuestion->type)
          !!}
      @endif
      <input type="hidden"
             name="participant_question_required[]"
             value="{{ $customQuestion->pivot->required }}">
      <input type="hidden"
             value="{{ $customQuestion->id }}"
             name="participant_question_id[]"/>
  </div>
@endforeach
```

Comment: what is `participant_question_required` field?

Comment: Just want to give you a quick heads up. I'm following your questions about your conference registration system for quite a while now and your questions are always very detailed, which is nice for people to be able to help. But I think you only get responses through bounties because you don't bring your questions on the point enough. For example do I miss an actual question within your question body right now. I.e., for me it isn't clear if you want to get your code fixed or if you are seeking advice on a design pattern. You'd be able to get an answer faster if you write more compact questions.

Comment: Please see this as advice, not as criticism. As stated, I like that you put a lot of effort into writing your questions. But in my experience, putting effort into reflecting before writing and compressing the actual question can be more valuable than writing down _all_ the information, because then other people need to understand a lot more context than normally necessary.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I've slightly modified the HTML file structure.

```
<form method="post" id="registration_form" action="http://proj.test/conference/1/conference-title/registration/storeRegistration">

{{csrf_field()}}

<h6>Participant - 1 - general</h6>
<div class="form-group">
    <label for="namegeneral_1">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="namegeneral_1" name="participant[1][name]" required="" class="form-control" value="">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="surnamegeneral_1">Surname</label>
    <input type="text" id="surnamegeneral_1" required="" class="form-control" name="participant[1][surname]" value="">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="participant_question">Phone?</label>
    <input type="text" name="participant[1][answer]" class="form-control" required="">
    <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="participant[1][question_id]">
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="participant[1][rtypes]" value="1">

<h6> Participant - 2 - general</h6>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="namegeneral_2">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="namegeneral_2" name="participant[2][name]" required="" class="form-control" value="">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="surnamegeneral_2">Surname</label>
    <input type="text" id="surnamegeneral_2" required="" class="form-control" name="participant[2][surname]" value="">
</div>

<div class="form-group">
    <label for="participant_question">Phone?</label>
    <input type="text" name="participant[2][answer]" class="form-control" required="">
    <input type="hidden" name="participant_question_required[]" value="1">
    <input type="hidden" value="1" name="participant[2][question_id]">
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="participant[2][rtypes]" value="1">

<h6> Participant - 1 - plus</h6>

<div class="form-group font-size-sm">
    <label for="nameplus_1">Name</label>
    <input type="text" id="nameplus_1" name="participant[3][name]" required="" class="form-control" value="">
</div>

<div class="form-group font-size-sm">
    <label for="surnameplus_1">Surname</label>
    <input type="text" id="surnameplus_1" required="" class="form-control" name="participant[3][surname]" value="">
</div>

<input type="hidden" name="participant[3][rtypes]" value="2">

<input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="Store Registration">
```

I will store all the ‍`participants` in an array named `participant` and send thme to `Backend`

output :

```
array:2 [▼
  "_token" => "WDtDV0CL6OKVCsGSi5HNyi4HQ6Pmo6VAwzDsgYK1"
  "participant" => array:3 [▼
    1 => array:5 [▼
      "name" => "ali"
      "surname" => "shahabi"
      "answer" => "0937"
      "question_id" => "1"
      "rtypes" => "1"
    ]
    2 => array:5 [▼
      "name" => "danyal"
      "surname" => "shahabi"
      "answer" => "0938"
      "question_id" => "1"
      "rtypes" => "1"
    ]
    3 => array:3 [▼
      "name" => "baba"
      "surname" => "babaei"
      "rtypes" => "2"
    ]
  ]
]
```

`storeRegistration` method .

I removed `validation` from the code and focused on the logic of the program:

```
public function storeRegistration(Request $request, $id, $slug = null)
{

    # all_participants field
    $allParticipants = Conference::where('id', $id)->first()->all_participants;

    $total = Session::get('total');

    # user object
    $user = Auth::user();

    # add registration to Database
    $registration = Registration::create([
        'conference_id' => $id,
        'main_participant_id' => $user->id,
        'status' => ($total > 0) ? 'I' : 'C',
    ]);

    # List of all participants
    $participants_list=$request->get('participant');

    #add all participants to Database
    foreach ($participants_list as $participant)
    {
        $name = ($allParticipants) ? $participant['name'] : '';
        $surname = ($allParticipants) ? $participant['surname'] : '';
        $participant_result = Participant::create([
            'name' => $name,
            'surname' => $surname,
            'registration_id' => $registration->id,
            'registration_type_id' => $participant['rtypes']
        ]);

        # save answer to Database if exist
        if(isset($participant['question_id']))
        {
            $answer = Answer::create([
                'question_id' => $participant['question_id'],
                'participant_id' => $participant_result->id,
                'answer' => $participant['answer'],
            ]);}
    }

    return redirect(route('user.index', ['user' => Auth::id()]).'#myTickets');
}
```

Comment: Thanks, can you explain better this part "    $participants_list=$request->get('participant');
"? And I have a getHtmlInput() function in the Question model to generate the necessary HTML for the custom questions to show on the view based on what is on database, I updated the question with that. I'm not understanding what is necessary to change so that the generated HTML matches your modified HTML.

Comment: In the registration form can appear (as it is in the question example) "  <h6>Participant - 1 - general</h6>" but 1 is not the id of the participant, because if it were, all users that do a registration in a conference will be the participant with id 1, but each participant should be unique. In the very first registration in the conference the participant_id will be 1 but in the next registration of another user or even the same user can do another registration in the same conference, the participant will need to have another unique id.

Comment: `$request->get('participant'); ` get all participant information from `view`.Look at the inputs. I changed the structure of their name.for example `name="participant[1][name]"`

Comment: in `name="participant[1][name]"` : The number 1, 2, and 3 is just for the convenience of working in the backend so that I can get the list of participants in an array.

Comment: Thanks, but so that numbers, for example, "1" here " participant[1][name]" should be the number of that? The participant id?

Comment: No . You can use a randomization number.
But note that the `inputs` of each `participant` have the `same number` in order to separate them in the backend.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/173262/discussion-between-alihossein-shahabi-and-johnw).

Comment: Thanks, but like that with an array of participants then how to validate the form fields? $request->all() shows for example based on what the user itnroduced in the form: " array:4 [▼ "_token" => """participant" => array:3 [▼  1 => array:5 [▼ "name" => "John" "surname" => null  "answer" => null  "question_id" => "1" "rtypes" => "1"] 2 => array:5 [▼  "name" => "ere"
  "surname" => "ere"  "answer" => "003"  "question_id" => "1" "rtypes" => "1"
 ] 3 => array:3 [▼ "name" => "i" "surname" => "i"
  "rtypes" => "2"
    ] ] "participant_question_required" => array:2 [▼
    0 => "1" 1 => "1"]
]".

Comment: But $rules show "array:4 [▼
  "participant_name.*" => "required|string"
  "participant_surname.*" => "required|string"
  "participant_question.0" => "required|string|max:255"
  "participant_question.1" => "required|string|max:255"
]", so the validation dont works because the fields are not in the rules properly.

Comment: You must change the ‍‍`$rules` and define new rules

Comment: Thanks! But same error defining the rules for the participants array like::

        $rules = [
            'participant.name' => 'required|string',
            'participant.surname' => 'required|string'
        ];